Angular 17v - Not able to open shared file path on Network in a new browser tab as it results in opening "about:blank#blocked"
I'm working on requirement using Angular 17 where I'm trying to open shared path on network.
I am using anchor tag to open folder location in a separate browser tab on click of link. Upon clicking it opens new browser tab however it redirects to about:blank#blocked URL.
If I manually try to access file path I'm able to do so.
Shared file path: file://xyz/
Not an ideal approach however I tried using jquery with Angular to open shared file path on Network but unable to do as it redirects to about:blank#blocked page.

file:// is for files on your computer. Afaik you will need to use http, https or ftp

I'm trying to open shared drive in browser.
